# Rename Property from Deserialized Javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, deserialization, custom-attributes

How do I take deserialize JavaScript and change the name of the property being processed?

For example:

```
class MyClass
{
public string CreateDate {get;set;}
}

public class DeserializeMyClass
{
//How do I take "create_date" and convert it to CreateDate? Is there an attribute I
//can use?
var json = @"{""create_date"":""04/12/2013""}";
var ds = new JavaScriptSerializer();

ds.Deserialize<MyClass>(json);

}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Aside - you probably don't want to pass dates like that.  You will have localization issues with various date formats.  Use an invariant format, such as ISO8601 `DateTime.ToString("o")` and pair with [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) in javascript.

Comment: Sure thing - I just wanted a quick example to throw up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you can't do it easily for JavaScriptSerializer, but you can do that in Json.Net  or using DataContractSerializer (part of .Net framework).

For Json.Net you can put JsonProperty attribute that specifies a name.

```
class MyClass
{
  [JsonProperty(Name="create_date")]
  public string CreateDate {get;set;}
}
```

And for DataContractSerializer use `DataMember` attribute

Comment: Is this found in a Microsoft assembly?

Answer (score 0):

There is no standard support for renaming properties in `JavaScriptSerializer` however you can quite easily add your own:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
using System.Reflection;

public class JsonConverter : JavaScriptConverter
{
    public override object Deserialize(IDictionary<string, object> dictionary, Type type, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)
    {
        List<MemberInfo> members = new List<MemberInfo>();
        members.AddRange(type.GetFields());
        members.AddRange(type.GetProperties().Where(p => p.CanRead && p.CanWrite && p.GetIndexParameters().Length == 0));

        object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(type);

        foreach (MemberInfo member in members)
        {
            JsonPropertyAttribute jsonProperty = (JsonPropertyAttribute)Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(member, typeof(JsonPropertyAttribute));

            if (jsonProperty != null && dictionary.ContainsKey(jsonProperty.Name))
            {
                SetMemberValue(serializer, member, obj, dictionary[jsonProperty.Name]);
            }
            else if (dictionary.ContainsKey(member.Name))
            {
                SetMemberValue(serializer, member, obj, dictionary[member.Name]);
            }
            else
            {
                KeyValuePair<string, object> kvp = dictionary.FirstOrDefault(x => string.Equals(x.Key, member.Name, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));

                if (!kvp.Equals(default(KeyValuePair<string, object>)))
                {
                    SetMemberValue(serializer, member, obj, kvp.Value);
                }
            }
        }

        return obj;
    }


    private void SetMemberValue(JavaScriptSerializer serializer, MemberInfo member, object obj, object value)
    {
        if (member is PropertyInfo)
        {
            PropertyInfo property = (PropertyInfo)member;                
            property.SetValue(obj, serializer.ConvertToType(value, property.PropertyType), null);
        }
        else if (member is FieldInfo)
        {
            FieldInfo field = (FieldInfo)member;
            field.SetValue(obj, serializer.ConvertToType(value, field.FieldType));
        }
    }


    public override IDictionary<string, object> Serialize(object obj, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)
    {
        Type type = obj.GetType();
        List<MemberInfo> members = new List<MemberInfo>();
        members.AddRange(type.GetFields());
        members.AddRange(type.GetProperties().Where(p => p.CanRead && p.CanWrite && p.GetIndexParameters().Length == 0));

        Dictionary<string, object> values = new Dictionary<string, object>();

        foreach (MemberInfo member in members)
        {
            JsonPropertyAttribute jsonProperty = (JsonPropertyAttribute)Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(member, typeof(JsonPropertyAttribute));

            if (jsonProperty != null)
            {
                values[jsonProperty.Name] = GetMemberValue(member, obj);
            }
            else
            {
                values[member.Name] = GetMemberValue(member, obj);
            }
        }

        return values;
    }

    private object GetMemberValue(MemberInfo member, object obj)
    {
        if (member is PropertyInfo)
        {
            PropertyInfo property = (PropertyInfo)member;
            return property.GetValue(obj, null);
        }
        else if (member is FieldInfo)
        {
            FieldInfo field = (FieldInfo)member;
            return field.GetValue(obj);
        }

        return null;
    }


    public override IEnumerable<Type> SupportedTypes
    {
        get 
        {
            return new[] { typeof(MyClass) };
        }
    }
}

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Field | AttributeTargets.Property)]
public class JsonPropertyAttribute : Attribute
{
    public JsonPropertyAttribute(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

The `MyClass` class then becomes:

```
class MyClass
{
     [JsonProperty("create_date")]
     public string CreateDate {get;set;}
}
```

I appreicate this might be a little late but thought other people wanting to use the `JavaScriptSerializer` rather than the `Json.Net` or 'DataContractJsonSerializer` might appreciate it.